# Reconhecer itens duplicados em uma lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou recebendo uma lista de itens em minha action

```
public ActionResult New(List<Itens> Itens)
{
   return View();
}
```

Como faço para reconhecer quais itens estão duplicados nessa lista?

Comment: Qual critério deve ser usado para saber se um item está duplicado??... por exemplo, quando `Item1.Id` for igual a `Item2.Id` (estou chutando)

Answer (score 5):

[O pacote MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) possui a ótima extensão de lista chamada `DistinctBy`:

```
var distinctList = Itens.DistinctBy(x => x.UmaPropriedadeQualquer).ToList();
```

Agora, se você quer saber só quem repetiu, seria algo como:

```
var repetidos = Itens
                 .GroupBy(x => x.UmaPropriedadeQualquer)
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                 .Select(g => g.Key)
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Podia postar apenas o [link para o SO.en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15866971/2556111) mas acho interessante termos a resposta aqui.

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "a", "b", "b", "r", "t" };

var distinct = new HashSet<string>();    
var duplicates = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var s in list)
    if (!distinct.Add(s))
        duplicates.Add(s);

// distinct == { "a", "b", "r", "t" }
// duplicates == { "a", "b" }
```

Só os [duplicados](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15866824/2556111)

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "b", "r", "t" };

var dups = list.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente se pode agrupar todos os itens dado um critério de agrupamento... e então colocamos cada agrupamento dentro de um dicionário:

```
var dicionarioDeArrays = lista
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());
```

Depois podemos filtrar o dicionário criado, para retornar apenas grupos que possuem um número X de elementos, no caso `> 1`:

```
var listaDeDuplicatasAgrupadasEmArrays = dicionarioDeArrays
    .Where(x => x.Value.Length > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

A vantagem desta abordagem é que ela é extremamente flexível... você pode por exemplo:

- agrupar usando uma propriedade:

  ```
  // agrupar pelo nome das pessoas (caso os itens sejam pessoas)
  .GroupBy(x => x.NomeDaPessoa)
  ```
- filtrar por quantidades diferentes:

  ```
  // quero pegar os trigêmeos (ou seja, 3 irmãos com o mesmo pai)
  .GroupBy(x => x.Pai)

  // ... e depois na hora de verificar, quero apenas os grupos com 3
  .Where(x => x.Value.Length == 3)
  ```